# Como transformar 2 form's em 1 só '

Tags: php, mysql, formulário

Bom dia pessoal,
 Tenho esses dois forms que seria um de entrada e um de saida,os dois fazem insert no banco,como poderia fazer para se tornarem 1 so:

```
<div class="col-md-6">
      <div class="panel panel-danger">
        <div class="panel-heading">ENTRADA</div>
          <div class="panel-body">
            <form class="form-horizontal" action="entrada.php" method="POST">
               <fieldset>
                 <div class="form-group">
                    <div class="col-md-12">
                    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="codigo" name="codigo" placeholder="CODIGO DO FUNCIONARIO">
                    </div>
                  </div>
                 <div class="form-group">
                    <center><button type="submit" class="btn btn-danger">ENTRAR</button></center>
                 </div>
               </fieldset>
           </form>
          </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-6">
      <div class="panel panel-danger">
        <div class="panel-heading">SAIDA</div>
          <div class="panel-body">
            <form class="form-horizontal" action="saida.php" method="POST">
               <fieldset>
                 <div class="form-group">
                    <div class="col-md-12">
                    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="codigo" name="codigo" placeholder="CODIGO DO FUNCIONARIO">
                    </div>
                  </div>
                 <div class="form-group">
                    <center><button type="submit" class="btn btn-danger">SAIR</button></center>
                 </div>
               </fieldset>
           </form>
          </div>
        </div>
```

O que seria 1 so,no banco eu tenho o status do funcionário,quando da entrada o form faz um update no status dele vai e ele vai  para 1 e quando da a saída vai para 0.

Não sei se consegui me expressar bem,caso alguém tenha algum duvida por favor me falar.

Comment: Ele faz um update ou faz um insert?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Se usa um UPDATE baseado no funcionário você pode usar isso:

```
UPDATE tabela SET status = IF (`status`, 0, 1) WHERE funcionario = ?
```

Dessa forma ele irá inverter entre 0 e 1.

Exemplo:

```
<form method="post">
<input type="text" name="funcionario">
<input type="submit">
</form>

<?php

if(isset($_POST['funcionario'])){

  $funcionario = $_POST['funcionario'];

  $update = $mysql->prepare("UPDATE tabela SET status = IF (`status`, 0, 1) WHERE funcionario = ?");

  $update->bind_param("s", $funcionario);
  $update->execute();

}

?>
```

Comment: Perfeito. Obrigado.